# If $Kerf_1 \cap Kerf_2 \subset Kerf$ then $ \exists k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f= k_1f_1 + k_2f_2$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f,f_1,f_2 : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ linear functions and $X$ is a vector space.
Prove that: 
If $Kerf_1 \cap Kerf_2 \subset Kerf \Rightarrow \exists k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f= k_1f_1 + k_2f_2$.

**My attempt:**
First I proved it only for $f,f_1$, That is :
If  $Kerf_1 \subset Kerf \Rightarrow \exists k_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f= k_1f_1 $

**Proof:**
If  $f_1=0 \quad \forall x \in X$ then it is trivial.

Now for $f_1 \neq 0 \Rightarrow \exists x_0 \in X : f_1(x_0)=0 \Rightarrow f(x_0)=0$

And

$\forall x \in X \quad x- \frac{f_1(x)}{f_1(x_0)}x_0\in Kerf_1 \subset Kerf$, 

Then

$f(x- \frac{f_1(x)}{f_1(x_0)}x_0)=0 \Rightarrow f(x)=\frac{f(x_0)}{f_1(x_0)}f_1(x)=f(x)=k_1f_1(x)$

So in this case $k_1= \frac{f(x_0)}{f_1(x_0)}$.

Now for the first statement i have to find a similar $x \in X $ s.t. $x \in Kerf_1 \cap Kerf_2 \subset Kerf$ and $f(x)$ would give a similar result, that is $x$ would be something like $x- \frac{f_1(x)}{f_1(x_0)}x_0- \frac{f_2(x)}{f_2(x_0)}x_0$.

I can't figure out what that $x$ is.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Updated!! Thanks

Comment: For finite dimensional vector spaces we have that $U^{\circ\circ}=U$ and that passing from $U$s to $U^{\circ}$s reverses inclusions and swaps sums and intersections. I think that would lead to a proof.